# Why do I get syntax error when I try to do a pip install on CentOS 6?

Tags: python-2.7, pip, centos

I'm trying to install a python module called **cymysql** on a CentOS 6 system by commands like

> yum install -y python-setuptools && easy_install pip && pip install cymysql

However I received an Error message saying there're a few lines got **SyntaxError: invalid syntax** ( see the error code as following)---It actually happened when I run the third command **pip install cymysql**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==21.0', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 561, in load_entry_point
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2631, in load_entry_point
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2291, in load
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2297, in resolve
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-21.0-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Not so sure what's happening here, just wondering if anyone can help? (I enclosed the pip file and main.py here but I don't know where is the init.py file).BTW, It's centOS 6 but I have installed the Python 3.6.10 on the server.When I run the command **python3.6 -V**, I got

> python3.6.10

FIY

PIP file Code:

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
 # EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'pip==21.0','console_scripts','pip'
 __requires__ = 'pip==21.0'
 import re
 import sys
 from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

 if __name__ == '__main__':
   sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
   sys.exit(
       load_entry_point('pip==21.0', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()  //**THIS IS LINE 11**
   )
```

Line 57 to 62 in Main.py

```
try:
    cmd_name, cmd_args = parse_command(args)
except PipError as exc:
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")  //**THIS IS LINE 60**
    sys.stderr.write(os.linesep)
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: pip 21.0 **py2.7**, see? Verify with `pip --version`

Answer (score 0):

#### **&tldr;**

On an RPM-based distro, you use RPM packages as much as possible.

#### Never run `pip` as root user

You [*must not* use `pip` as root user](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/do-not-run-pip-as-root) (or asking for trouble).
There is a whole infrastructure of Python packages installable through `yum` and this is what you should use.

You can still use `pip` to install Python modules, but only in very rare cases when a Python module is not available as a package. In that case you *must* use `pip` inside a virtual Python environment. Your case is such.

Make sure you have [fixed `yum` for base, EPEL and set up SCLO repositories](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/how-to-fix-yum-after-centos-6-went-eol), since CentOS 6 is EOL.

Then:

```
# Ensure EPEL repository
yum -y install epel-release
# fix EPEL repo due to EOL:
curl https://www.getpagespeed.com/files/centos6-epel-eol.repo --output /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo
yum -y install centos-release-scl-rh
# don't forget to fix repository configuration due to EOL:
curl https://www.getpagespeed.com/files/centos6-scl-eol.repo --output /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-SCLo-scl.repo
curl https://www.getpagespeed.com/files/centos6-scl-rh-eol.repo --output /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-SCLo-scl-rh.repo
# install python 3.6 from Software collection packages (installing virtualenv will pick up both the base python and its pip package)
yum -y install rh-python36-python-virtualenv
```

Now you can create a virtual environment with any packages from pip, but you have to activate the software collection in your shell first, example:

```
. /opt/rh/rh-python36/enable
cd ${HOME}
# create "myapp" virtual environment
virtualenv myapp 
# install desired packages using virtualenv's pip (will install to the virtualenv and not damage your system)
./myapp/bin/pip install cymysql
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not go over pip version 20 on a Centos 6 system, otherwise wheels with precompiled c libraries will break.
Long story short, do this first:

```
pip install --upgrade pip==20.1.0
```

After that you can install cymysql